# How to resolve output result from crontab different with the output result by manually running the script?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

How to resolve if output result in text file from crontab is different from the output result when i manually run the script in Linux?

Example :

Ifconfig output from crontab is empty.

Thanks!

```
SHELL=/bin/sh

0 0 * * * /usr/lib/secchk/security-daily.sh >> /var/security-daily.log
15 0 * * mon /usr/lib/secchk/security-weekly.sh >> /var/security-weekly.log
45 0 1 * * /usr/lib/secchk/security-monthly.sh >> /var/security-monthly.log
1,31 * * * * /var/stats_chperm.sh >> /var/chperm.log
16,46 * * * * /var/stats_chperm.sh >> /var/chperm.log
0 16 * * * /usr/sbin/aide --check
0 1 * * * /opt/ipworks/IPWbackup/scripts/ipwbr backup
00 22 * * * /home/songpen/DNSHC2.sh
```

Comment: Post the full cron entry.

Comment: Please rather edit your question.

Comment: There if no `ifconfig` entry in your task list. Is it in one of the scripts? If so, what's the run string? Also, you have specified the Bourne shell, but tagged `bash`.